# google maps w/ firefox 83 ubuntu 20.04 no 3D earth view

Tags: firefox, nvidia-geforce, google-maps

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with firefox 83. 3D earth view was working well but since a few days, I don't have 3d anymore.

GC: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]

I try performance (preferences) but no change.